# sudo (not I) remember my password

Tags: sudo

Trying to upgrade my ubuntu. I haven't used it in a while and want to upgrade it to 13.10
I understand I have to go from 12.04 to 12.10 to 13.04 to 13.10.
But when I am in the terminal and enter

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and the terminal asks me for my password. When I enter it in, it informs me "Sorry, try again". I already went in recovery and reset my password thinking I forgot it but it still will not take the new password. What can I do?

P.S. I'm a beginner at linux. Sorry if I did not include any information that will help you guys help me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try running `sudo -i` to check if it's a problem with your password / `sudo`?

Comment: su root recognized my password. I think it has to do with the sudo commands. @DavidsonChua

Comment: Do you have a root user if you used `su root`? In which case, you can try running `do-release-upgrade` after `su root`

Comment: No upgrade was found? @DavidsonChua

Comment: After running `su root`, and you have a `#` prompt, try running `adduser <username> sudo` as Chester suggested, then returning to your own account and using `sudo do-release-upgrade`, if it's a problem with your account not being a `sudo`er.

Comment: The user <username> is already a member of 'sudo'

Comment: This _is_ a strange problem. Try using `passwd` from your user account to change your password, and see if it works.

Comment: I double checked to see if it will look for new updates or just LTS versions. I updated that and now it seems to work.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept an answer to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Try `su root` then enter your password.

If it says "Sorry, try again" it means that you are entering the wrong password.

As you have said that you are not using an account password, I would strongly suggest that you do for added security. I believe that you are not able to `sudo` because your account doesn't have a password. Remember that `su` uses the `root` password while `sudo` uses your account password. This might be the reason why `su root` works and `sudo` doesn't.

After adding an account password, add your account to the `sudoers` group by `adduser <username> sudo`

If it succeeds, you should have root privileges. Upon attaining root, type `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: My password was correct when inputting         su root but when using the sudo command it does not recognize it. I went into update manager settings and changed 'Notify my of a new Ubuntu version: For long-term support versions' // to 'For any new release' . It asks for my password but still did not accept it. upon entering         do-release-upgrade , ubuntu checked for a new release but did not find any.

Comment: Are you a member of the sudoers group? Maybe you can try to add your user account to it. Try `sudo su` then `adduser <username> sudo`

Comment: Still ask for password when using sudo commands @chester

Comment: Sorry, just edited my previous comment. Please try above.

Comment: Still requires me to enter in a password, in which I still get the same response "Sorry, try again".

Comment: @Chester If he's not a `sudo`er, he can't run `sudo su`. In which case RazaHuss needs to log in as a `sudo`er.

Comment: @DavidsonChua, yeah thanks, haven't noticed. @RazaHuss, try `su root` then `adduser <username> sudo`. By the way, are you using the correct password? Remember that `su` uses the `root` password while `sudo` uses your account password.

Comment: I see but I don't use a account password. I seemed to get it updating now. It's actually updating to 14.04... Thanks for you help guys!

Comment: @RazaHuss, I have updated the answer. If it answered your question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation, there are a few possible problems with your setup.

To identify the problem, take the following steps (this not only applies to RazaHuss, but also anyone encountering similar problems):

1. Try running `sudo -i`. If it works, the problem is not with your `sudo`. Check your release upgrade settings under System Settings -> Software and Sources. If the problem is with `sudo`, move on to step 2.
2. If it returns the same problem, check if you are a sudoer. Log into a sudoer account or become root using `su`, and run `adduser <username> sudo`. If this does not solve the problem, move on to step 3.
3. As your user account, run `passwd` and try setting your password again to make sure the problem is not with your password.

Answer (score 0):

If you run upgrade you should add -d. So run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Advice: Clean install will be much simpler. Download the latest Ubuntu from Official website and Install it .

Bacause first of all  for upgrading  to 13.10 you have to upgrade to 12.10 -> 13.04 -> 13.10.  it will be tedious process and waste your time and Internet Data Usage as well.

And the chances of Appearing `Errors` will be more, kernel issues . So just make a new fresh installation , after making backup of Home and copying `source list` .

hope it helped you.